# Odoo9, what's wrong when I change my models.py? in windows PC

Tags: python, windows, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

first at all I'm new in Odoo development (and Python).

I'm trying to apply this [tutorial](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/backend.html) as a demo version for my first application with Odoo9.

All things is working good except when I change my models.py : Add a new class or a new field for example (Like in 'Relations between models' in tutorial's exercice) ... Odoo9 dont get the new class directly even when I try to : Update, upgrade my app, or uninstall and install the app... Then I need to restart my pc to get the correct result ! Sure there is another solution, any help please ?

Comment: Please, add your code

Comment: you can update the module by -u your_module_name

Comment: @LucaDetomi, The code is in the link above : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/backend.html

Comment: @JainikPatel Where can I use this line ? Cmd ?

Comment: @LucaDetomi The problem isn't in the code but : How can I restart models.py, or the server or whatever ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you given Technical Features rights to users??

If not then give it like this:

To activate the technical features, you have to add access rights to your user. You must edit your current user from the menu Settings > Users. Edit your user (probably admin) and, in the Access Rights tab, check the option Technical Features.

Then, update Modules List menu going to Settings/Modules/Update Modules List

In odoo 9 , they are apps (modules) , click on the option Apps , you will get list of apps that you can install..
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5j41T1Hqv1sTnFYSncwRlk3emM/view?usp=drivesdk
http://goo.gl/9hPlFP

Install the ones you want , and there are already filters (installed, Not Installed etc)..

Regarding the technical settings : You have to Activate the Developer Mode for that , and then automatically the technical features will be enabled to the current user ..

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5j41T1Hqv1sbnBlVFhnN2Y3Rk0/view?usp=drivesdk (click on About odoo)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5j41T1Hqv1sMmhwa1hOWVRUMU0/view?usp=drivesdk
(Click on "Activate the Developer Mode")

**Or Restart Server Throw This One**

Go to Menu Start --> Type : Services --> search OpenERP or Odoo Server --> Select line and click on Restart/Start/Stop's buttons above – by  **@Nilesh Sheliya**

Answer (score 1):

You have to restart the Odoo server to affect the changes done in models.py. Once server restarted, you need to upgrade the module to add newly created fields in database. You don't need to restart PC.

On which OS(Windows, Ubuntu, Mac) are you using Odoo V9 ?

Comment: Windows. How can I restart the server ? cmd ?

Comment: Go to Menu Start --> tape Services --> search OpenERP or odoo Server --> Select line and click on Restart/Start/Stop's buttons above

Comment: That's what I need :) thanks a lot. The name of service is "odoo-server-9.0 9.0".